# Why isn't IIS finding an AJAX DLL registered in the page through server tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, dll

This is similar to a number of questions (listed below) but slightly different, and the answers for those don't seem to work on this one.

ASP solution developed in VS2008, target .Net 2.0.50727.  Works OK on live server but not my localhost or the test server.

In VS, the AjaxControlToolkit DLL is included as a reference in the project.  It shows in the object browser as having the classes required.

The web page includes a server tag:

`<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>`

Then later, has one of the controls from this DLL:

VS complains that CC1 is an unrecognised tag prefix.  The project compiles and builds OK but when running a session in the browser, when a control is clicked which sends a query for this page to handle, IIS throws a parse error complaining that it cannot find a different DLL:

> Parser Error Message: Unable to create type
>   'cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender'. Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Sorry if this is basic, but I've been trying for several hours to get it sorted.  I've looked at these:

[register-a-dll-on-a-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550589/element-x-is-not-a-known-element-web-application)

[why-is-my-dll-failing-to-register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570382/why-is-my-dll-failing-to-register)

[element-x-is-not-a-known-element-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550589/element-x-is-not-a-known-element-web-application)

Comment: One of AjaxControlToolkit's dependency is missing. Easiest way will be to re-install AjaxControlToolkit via NuGet like this - `Update-Package –reinstall AjaxControlToolkit`

Comment: Thanks Win, I'll try that and post the results.

Comment: Adding NuGet to VS2008 looks like a small project in its own right!  Is there another way to sort these dependencies?

Comment: NuGet creates a folder called packages, downloads correct assemblies based on your run-time, and adds reference to your project. ***FYI**: NuGet did not add actually project to your existing project.*

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a DLL version problem.  The project target was .Net 2.0 but the reference for System.Web.Extensions had been made to v3.5.0.0 (which VS wouldn't normally permit, so it must have been done manually or by temporarily altering the target architecture).  Changing the reference to the earlier 1.0.61025.0 and adding a couple of sections to Web.config to force it to be invoked fixed the problem:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <!-- [04/12/2014 SS] added to correct the JSON request/response format whilst retaining Sys web extensions v1 -->
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
    <!-- [end] -->
</httpHandlers>
```

and

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
  <!-- [04/12/2014 SS] added to get over ASP parser failing to recognise script manager -->
  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </controls>
  </pages>
  <!-- [end] -->
</system.web>
```